# How to get a price for Uniswap three legged trade

Tags: web3js, uniswap, swaps

Hi i see that this question has been asked a few times but no direct answer is there anywhere.

I want to get the path through which a swap can take place between any 2 tokens, even if the pool dosent exist.

I want to get the outamount if i enter any 2 tokens even the ones which dont have a direct pool.

Thanks.